# Is there a method to get a custom customer attribute value from a drop-down attribute through the Magento soap API?

Tags: api, soap, magento-1.7, customer-attribute

I have extended the Magento soap API in a custom module via wsi.xml and wsdl.xml to bring in a custom attribute added to my customers. The extension works fine to bring in the custom attributes I add via the back-end. However, if that attribute is a drop-down, the value retrieved through the API is the drop-down's option id.

I am retrieving my custom attributes via customerCustomerInfo. As seen in the [Magento API documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/customer/customer.info.html). I have provided my wsi.xml and wsdl.xml below for clarity's sake.

Is there a way to get the actual option name through the soap API instead of the id?

wsi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="Magento" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <xsd:complexType name="customerCustomerEntity">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="customertype" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" ></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

wsdl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <complexType name="customerCustomerEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="customertype" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15267/custom-api-v2-not-working?rq=1

Comment: @B00MER I'm not sure how that's related. The API works fine for me. I just can't find a method that would allow getting the value of a custom drop-down value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method implemented in the standard Magento SOAP API to get the attributes value instead of the id.

The attributes are collected in the `info()` function of `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer_Api`:
lines 98-104 (as for CE 1.8.1.0)

```
   foreach ($this->_mapAttributes as $attributeAlias=>$attributeCode) {
       $result[$attributeAlias] = $customer->getData($attributeCode);
   }

   foreach ($this->getAllowedAttributes($customer, $attributes) as attributeCode=>$attribute) {
        $result[$attributeCode] = $customer->getData($attributeCode);
   }
```

So you might want to extend it there.